# finding all Strong tags with beautifulsoup returns an empty array

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract all strings included in strong tags and save them in a file. But I cannot extract strong tags; it only returns empty array. Am I missing anything. Here is the code that I have used:
Input:

```
>>>Import requests
>>>from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>r=requests.get(' http://www.webmd.com/heart-disease/heart-disease-glossary#1')
>>>r.content
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
>>>print(soup)
>>>soup.find_all('strong')
```

Output for the last statement:

```
[]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are there any strong tags in the source?  I followed your link and I didn't see anything inside a strong tag.

Comment: @meisen99 you are right, I needed to look for <b> instead of <strong>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there **isn't** a ***strong*** tag in the soup.

When open the url in a browser, you can get two strong tags. But I don't think you need them.

```
<li xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Check the address for typing errors such as
<strong>ww</strong>.example.com instead of
<strong>www</strong>.example.com</li>
```

If you mean to get all the terms in bold, you should use .find_all('b').

```
[tag.text.strip().replace(':',"") for tag in soup.find_all('b')]
```

outputs:

```
['Ablation','Advance Directive (living will)','Aerobic Exercise', ...]
```